# function adding data at the end of a linked list

Tags: c

it's my first post here , to resume I have  a problem in a function which add data in the end of my list .. 
this is my code :
(there are some rq in the code ) 
thanks

```cpp
typedef struct noeud {
    char c;
    struct noeud * next;
} Noeud;

typedef Noeud * car;

//for crt a dat in the last of the list
car addInLast(car T, char x) {
    car temp = malloc(sizeof(Noeud));
    car dat = malloc(sizeof(Noeud));
    temp = T;
    while (temp) {
        temp = temp - > next;
    }
    dat - > c = x;
    dat - > next = NULL;
    temp = dat;
    return T;
}
// crt in the frst
car addInFirst(car T, char x) {
    car temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Noeud));
    temp - > c = x;
    temp - > next = T;
    T = temp;
    return T;
}
```

it didn't add anything and the length still the same ..  what is the problem please ?
   *Thanks a lot for your participations*

Comment: Could you give us more of the code? We don't have enough to diagnose the problem

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez We do, actually. `addInLast` allocates and sets the fields of `dat`, but `dat` is never attached to the list ... it is just put into the local variable `temp`, and then the memory is leaked when the function is returned. (The memory allocated in the first line and assigned to `temp` is also leaked, as `temp` is immediately overwritten.)

Comment: It looks like you're right! Sorry 'bout that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The function `addInLast` has some flaws. Consider this loop:

```
while (temp) {
    temp = temp - > next;
}
```

This will continue until `temp` is null, and has no more connection to the list. The function then puts the new data in a new structure, and returns a pointer to the original list. *Nothing has been added to the list.*

Something like this might be better:

```
while (temp->next) {
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

There are other problems, and you must still be careful with unusual cases, such as adding an element to an empty list, but this should be enough to start with.

In future, it is wise to post [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than code excerpts.

Comment: so what should I add ?

Comment: My function creats a pointer and makes data there .. the last temp which is pointing to NULL goes to point to this pointer .. the function returns the listhead pointer

Comment: @MouadBlej: You're right, my mistake, I'll edit. But still, nothing is added to the list.

Comment: ohhh that's great .. I will try .. thanks for the help

Comment: same problem .. nothing added

Comment: @MarkBenningfield it returns my first pointer ( the listhead pointer )

Comment: @MouadBlej: Once you have a pointer to the last node, what do you do with it? Do you redirect the pointer to something else, breaking the connection again? You must think through the logic; if you just modify the code without understanding, it will take a very long time to find a solution.

Comment: my last pointer will be NULL so I give it it to the new one called data to take its values

Comment: @MouadBlej: No, you are changing the wrong pointer. You must master simpler pointer exercises before you attempt a linked list.

Comment: @MouadBlej The first two lines of `addInLast` allocate memory, but both of those allocations are leaked, as the pointers to them are never stored in memory. I recommend drawing pictures to keep track of what is in each variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in addInLast code, below is the function with issues resolved and I added comments to explain the issues

```
car addInLast(car T, char x) {
    car temp = NULL; // No Need to allocate new space for this pointer, we use 
                    // this pointer to traverse to end of list
    car dat = malloc(sizeof(Noeud));
    dat - > c = x;
    dat - > next = NULL;
    temp = T;

    if(temp == NULL){ // If the list is empty first node will be the node you 
                     // created
        T = dat;
        return T;
    }

    while (temp->next != NULL){ // This condition makes sure you reach the last 
                                // element of the list because for last elemt 
                                // next value is NULL
        temp = temp - > next;
    } 
    temp->next = dat;
    return T;
}
```

Comment: You treated the case when the T==NULL .. it's good thing .. but I supposed to have a list so what is the difference between this : while (temp->next != NULL){ 
        temp = temp - > next;
    } 
    temp->next = dat;
    return T }  and my while loop

Comment: i worked with temp in the loop and gived dat to temp .. you worked with temp->next and gived dat to temp->next .. i think it's the same but the mine didn't work

Comment: @MouadBlej: The condition you were checking for is essentially Temp != NULL, when the while loop reaches the last element if the next assignment you make Temp = Temp-> next which is NULL, hence you lost the pointer to the last element, which you don't want. I suggest you to work on some simple pointer exercises and then watch few tutorial videos on linked list.

Comment: @MouadBlej "i think it's the same" -- no, they are very different, and this is the misunderstanding that you need to master. `temp` is just a local variable that contains a memory address, it's not a memory location. `temp->next` is a memory location -- storing into it changes your list. Setting `temp` does not.

Comment: @JimBalter aha thank you a lot for your instructions .. I did a big error